# How to restrict users on Azure Portal

Tags: azure

We have Azure Enterprise subscription and I am the recent administrator. A group of IS auditors want to take a look at Network, NSG and other related stuff so we want to provide  read only access to them. Can anyone guide how to provide them readonly access there.and they cannot access anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone guide how to provide them readonly access there.and they
> cannot access anything else

You can make use of `Azure Role-based Access Control (RBAC)` to do exactly that. With Azure RBAC, you can grant granular-level permission on resources to resources in an Azure Subscription to the users. In this case, you can assign the auditors a `Reader` role on the resources (Network, NSG etc.) and they will only see the resources that they have access to.

You can learn more about Azure RBAC here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview.